# HTML to PDF using dompdf

Tags: php, html, css, dompdf

I am trying to use `dompdf` to convert `HTML` to `PDF`. The format that I am trying to match is:
[image: correct format]

However, the generated PDF has the following formatting issue:
[image: The format i am getting]

The attributes for the first column are:

```
<td style="width:85% !important;"><p>asdasdasd</p></td>
```

The attributes for the second column are:

```
<td style="width:100px;vertical-align:top; text-align:center;">1234</td>
```

Any solutions?

Comment: try removing the `width:85% !important` and just have `width:100px;` in the second `td`.

Comment: The two `width` declarations conflict with each other unless you know that 100px is always precisely 15% of the available space, and even if that were the case then one of them would be superfluous. You need to decide which one you want - should the left column be 85% or should the right column be 100px?

Comment: What's the dompdf version ? I have the latest beta and width css attributes works just nice and automagically. Not sure about !important though

Comment: i tried setting width to 15% in the second td but the error remains!

Comment: the latest one 0-6-0 beta 3

Comment: @Prisoner doing that in the resultant pdf the second column isnt printed at all!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry for the late answer but it had something to do with css related to the table.Little bit of tweaking and the error was gone.
We had to provide fixed width dimension in the css to solve it.